# Оптимизация unity3d

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

Вчера смотрел один урок по разработке в unity3d. Урок был об обработке столкновений, не понял одну вещь, касательно оптимизации. Может кто-то раскроет тему более подробно.

Насколько мне стало известно в unity3d объекты которые имеют колайдер и компонент rigidbody делятся на 2 типа: статические и динамические.

- Как понять к какому типу относится объект? И какой из этих типов
  находится в кэше?
- Я так понимаю нужно стараться чтобы как можно меньше объектов
  находилось в кэше одновременно?

Comment: Вопросы наверное довольно простые, так что прошу прощения,  я совсем новенький в этой сфере)

Comment: ну если упрощённо [дальше мои домыслы, как бы я реализовывал], то юнити строит декартово дерево для быстрого расчёта столкновений "огрничивающих коробок", если объект не выходит за рамки своей коробки (неподвижен или вращается) то его не нужно перестраивать в дереве и следовательно работает всё примерно за (log ^ 2 (N) N - число объектов). Если нужно перестроить дерево, то соответсвенно это ещё лишние операции + балансировка дерева + выделения памяти. Если коллайдер простой формы (прямоугольник) то на этом рассчёт заканчивается, иначе нужно для всех подозрительных объектов делать ещё

Comment: пересечение их коллайдеров примерно за `sum(i,j 1,N) A[i]*A[j] `- каждая пара подозрительных объектов за произведение числа вершин (ну может чуть быстрее). Поэтому если вы "собираете пазл", то это будет тормозить.
Оптимизации - простая форма, минимум перемещений (лучше камеру двигайте), минимум "зацепов" объектов. Пишу в комментарии т.к. не уверен в правильности.

Answer (score 2):

На объектах который вы рассматриваете есть компонента `Rigidbody` или `Rigidbody2D` если работаете в 2D. У них есть признак `Is Kinematic`, если установлен то такой объект статический, им можно управлять из кода, если сброшен то управляет объектом PhysX, а вы в идеале только силу и импульс к нему прикладываете чтобы заставить его двигаться. На кинематику не действует гравитация, а динамические объекты ей подвержены если в `Rigidbody` сделаны соответствующие настройки.